# Proof that the convergence of a series is unique

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Define the following:

$\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=a$ means: For all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$, one has $|a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon$

$\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=\infty$ means: For all $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$ one has $ \sum_{s\in T'} f(s) >M$

Then prove: If $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)$ converges to $a$ and to $b$, prove that $a = b$.

Here is my proof:

Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)$ converges to $a$ and to $b$ for $a\ne b$. That is for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $T_1\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T_1'\subseteq S$ that contain $T_1$, one has $|a-\sum_{s\in T_2'} f(s)|<\epsilon$. Also for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $T_2\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T_2'\subseteq S$ that contain $T_2$, one has $|b-\sum_{s\in T_2'} f(s)|<\epsilon$. So let $\epsilon=\frac{|a-b|}{2}$. Then there exists $T'$ such that $|b-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon$ and $|a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon$. Now consider $|a-b|$. Then $|a-b|=|a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)+\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)-b| \le |a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|+|\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)-b|= |a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|+|b-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon+\epsilon = 2\epsilon$. Therefore $a\ne b$ leads to a contradiction. So if $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)$ converges to $a$ and to $b$, then $a = b$.

Does this proof work and if so is it clear enough. It makes sense to me, but I'm wrong more than I'm right.

Comment: You're missing the case $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b=\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. I would have taken a shorter path though, when obtaining $|a-b| < 2\epsilon$, since that holds for all $\epsilon$, then $a = b$. But yours is perfectly fine.